# Can't install a single dependency or activate virtualenv using pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies, pipenv, pipenv-install

I have seen some similar questions but none of those answers fixed my problem.

So the thing is, i installed pipenv and tried to use it to be able to create a pipefile, but i can't, i also got one pair of pipefile and pipefile.lock and tried to install but whenever i try it gives me this:

***for example, lets say i want to install requests***

```
PS D:\Projetos\Python\shipay\backend-challenge\bot> pipenv install requests
Installing requests...
Pipfile.lock (d5437b) out of date, updating to (c4c73e)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
[   =] Resolving dependencies...
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] python setup.py egg_info exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:/Users/leand/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 812, in _main     
[ResolutionFailure]:       pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, category
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:/Users/leand/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 767, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:/Users/leand/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 747, in resolve   
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:/Users/leand/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 1109, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:/Users/leand/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 899, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:/Users/leand/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/site-packages/pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 687, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: metadata generation failed
```

***Here's the Pipefile:***

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
apscheduler = "*"
flask = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
xlsxwriter = "*"
logging = "*"
requests = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

i just got errors, i can't install a single one, and if i enter the `pipenv install --skip-lock` it doesn't show me nothing at all.

and the code pointed me: ***Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.***

also, this line `pipenv lock --pre --clear` that i saw on other post does the same error above

what i need to do here? or am i missing something here?